# Extracting values from pgfplotstable into array of variables based on condition

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I have data regarding Attributes and Values, e.g.

Attribute Abbreviation Value Atr1 Abb1 20 Atr2 Abb2 0 Atr3 Abb3 60 Atr4 Abb4 0 ....

Based on the value of the attributes, I should display the list of attributes in minipage environment... I need to display all atributes whose values are higher than zero..

I've tried to do this with filecontents and pgfplotstable, but somehow I only get values from one row that is placed after the last row with values..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc} \usepackage{afterpage} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{spy} \usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning} \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} \usetikzlibrary{arrows} \usepackage{filecontents} \usepackage{pgfplotstable} \usepackage{ifthen} \usepackage{etoolbox} \usepackage{tabulary} \usepackage{arrayjobx,datatool,multirow,forloop}

\begin{filecontents*}{topatributtes.csv} Name, Abbreviation, Percentage Atribute1, R, 0 Atribute2, I, 0 Atribute3, A, 70 Atribute4, S, 35 Atribute5, E, 0 Atribute6, C, 0 \end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{topatributtes.csv}\datatableA

\newarray\Attributes \newarray\Values \newcounter{nr} \stepcounter{nr} \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatableA} \pgfmathsetmacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} \foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable} { \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Percentage}\of{\datatableA}\global\let\LabelValue=\pgfplotsretval \ifthenelse{\LabelValue > 0}{ \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatableA}\global\let\AbbrName=\pgfplotsretval\Values(\arabic{nr})=\LabelValue \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Name}\of{\datatableA}\global\let\LabelName=\pgfplotsretval\Attributes(\arabic{nr})=\LabelName \stepcounter{nr}}{}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{236.3px} \vspace*{10px} \centering{\fontsize{16px}{30px}\selectfont\textsl{Top Compatibility Attributes}} \newcounter{st}% \addtocounter{nr}{-1} \begin{itemize} \forloop{st}{1}{\not{\value{st} > \value{nr}}}{% \item \Attributes(\arabic{st}) \Values(\arabic{st}) } \end{itemize} \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have a dynamic list, something like this

Attribute3

Attribute5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! To be honest there are many things that I do not understand in your code. However, the following prints only the positive values. Maybe it is something you can build on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 

\begin{filecontents*}{topatributtes.csv} 
Name, Abbreviation, Percentage 
Atribute1, R, 0 
Atribute2, I, 0 
Atribute3, A, 70 
Atribute4, S, 35 
Atribute5, E, 0 
Atribute6, C, 0 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{236.3px} 
\vspace*{10px} 
\centering\fontsize{16px}{30px}\selectfont\textsl{Top Compatibility Attributes}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{topatributtes.csv}\datatableA
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatableA} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable} 
{\pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Percentage}\of{\datatableA}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\pgfplotsretval)}
\ifnum\itest=1
\pgfplotsretval\par
\fi
}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]